# Trying to create a 2 x 12 heatmap in ggplot2 "Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (12): x"

Tags: r, heatmap

I'm trying to create a 2-column 12-row heatmap using geom_tile with ggplot2 in R.

I've tried a number of ways of setting the axes in aes()

```
db <- read.csv("db.csv")

ggplot(db, aes(x=colnames(db), y=rownames(db))) + 
         geom_tile()
```

or

```
ggplot(db, aes(x=db[,2:3], y=rownames(db))) + 
             geom_tile()
```

I get the following error:
"Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (12): x"

It's like it's trying to force me to have a square heatmap and I'm not sure how to circumvent this. Should I reshape my .csv file?

This is my .csv:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoZsA.png)

Comment: You need to reshape your data frame, not your csv file, to a longer format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - you need to reshape your data, and use the values as the `fill` argument.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

pivot_longer(df, 2:3) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, GN, fill=value)) +
  geom_tile()
```

[image]

---

**Data**: (simulated)

```
df <- structure(list(GN = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", 
"i", "j", "k", "l"), plus = c(0.586, -0.988, -0.6246, 0.3637, 
-0.2598, -0.2767, 0.7376, 0.8083, 0.2348, -0.7319, 0.5644, -0.1416
), minus = c(0.8545, 0.5465, -0.4806, -0.3576, -0.8796, -0.9131, 
-0.8899, 0.2511, 0.9289, 0.6546, -0.3699, -0.5739)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: thank you Edward, for future reference, how should I structure my .csv for a heatmap? To me, this df object you have created looks like it is in the same format: 3 columns each with 12 rows. I'm also interested in knowing how you copied the content of my file so quickly.

Comment: I didn't copy it, I simulated my own. The original data has 3 columns but ggplot wants "tidy" data, so you need to reshape it before plotting. You can also keep the original data in your preferred format if it is easier for data entry, as long as you reshape it in R before plotting. Look at the result of `pivot_longer` to see what tidy data looks like.